# Movie with cyberpunk-like villain set in jungle

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I am trying to find a movie which I watched long ago (somewhere in the 90s) as a kid on VHS tape. Another movie was copied over the movie I am searching for, and because of that, I only watched part of the movie.

The movie was in English, not sure when it was released, and for a long period of time I thought that Lorenzo Lamas was in the main role, but when I check out Lorenzo Lamas movies, I don't find anything similar to this one.
All I can remember are just few scenes and one specific character – villain.
I asked my co-worker on the job, and he also say that he remembers few scenes + one i remembering. We think for 90-95% that its the same movie we think of.
There is what we remembers:

### Co-worker

The dude in some jeep (without the roof - i remember also to be without roof) is chasing with some other vehicles (all are jeeps presumed), and how he escape from them, he somehow ?crush? in the river to half of his jeep.

### C-W & ME

A girl is in a jeep which is half in the river, while the main male character (lets call him further Lorenzo because I think it was him) is nearby in the water and something like washing something or himself... or maybe even trying to catch a fish with his hat (not so sure about this). The girl find a big piece of meat and try to ''wash/clean'' it in the river. She shouts to Lorenzo something like, "
"Look, I make a dinner" and he responds "throw it." When she looks again to the meat, she sees that piranhas have grabbed it and eaten half of it!
She throws it in the river, Lorenzo jumps in the jeep, and they escape from the river. From this scene, I think that maybe the movie is set in the Amazon, because piranhas live there.

### Co-worker

The main character use to repair his jeep (not sure is it before or after piranhas scene), and in that scene girl is shows to be a little dumb, what shows movie to be a bit comedy.

### ME

Some wild tribe catches that same girl, and Lorenzo comes to rescue her. The girl is bound to something, those savages jumping around/dancing... fire is there... and Lorenzo succeeds in pushing a big rock from some higher point on the tribe, and they run / spread around. He comes and rescues the girl – now i am not sure but I think I remember that there is one more man in that scene – who sacrifices himself, because this tribe starts returning. When I talk with my brother about this movie, he says that he doesn't remember anything except that some tribe tries to sacrifice a woman.

### ME

There is the villain with a mask like [this](https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/b8a58173-4e31-4256-96eb-13c4a5db3cc9/d71owl6-98286e88-b814-4385-ab7a-1802396defb6.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3sicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYjhhNTgxNzMtNGUzMS00MjU2LTk2ZWItMTNjNGE1ZGIzY2M5XC9kNzFvd2w2LTk4Mjg2ZTg4LWI4MTQtNDM4NS1hYjdhLTE4MDIzOTZkZWZiNi5qcGcifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6ZmlsZS5kb3dubG9hZCJdfQ.kM4-iARjyC7RGyaNVCS1txXq__PeMFT24DWlIACBfHI). The eyes might have been glowing red or blue. Or maybe they even changed colors, not sure. Also not sure if he a robot or cyborg. Maybe he just has a mask. The most interesting thing about him is that every time he is shown, he is in some cave and plays some tech pipe organ, and it sounds like Dark Tech Organ Choirs! The noise of it in my memory is somehow sharp and unbearable.
This same villain captures that girl I previously mentioned, and Lorenzo come to rescue her. Somewhere in that battle, Lorenzo tries to shoot this villain with some rifle, but it malfunctions or maybe the bullet bounces off of the villain's armor (not sure)! Then Lorenzo manages to smash/crush/kill the villain with the rock! The rock smashed the villain into the wall (or something like that) and on the side of rock is seen his hand to collapse – like he finally died!

### C-W & ME

Now i'm not so sure is this from the same movie, although Co-worker think that it is.
The movie ends with male and female character walking/climbing over some red quarry or it was a hill/mount with a lot of rocks.  Now maybe its red daybreak or red twilight.

There is a bunch of movies from my research to discard:

- Indiana Jones movies
- Alan Quatermain movies
- Romancing The Stone (1984)
- The Jewel of the Nile (1985)
- The Treasure of the Sierra Madre (1948)
- The Librarian movies
- The Goonies (1985)
- Snake Eater movies
- Black Dawn (Good Cop, Bad Cop) (1997)
- Journey to the Center of the Earth (2008)  and its sequel
- Eight Hundred Leagues Down the Amazon (1993)
- The Further Adventures Of Tennessee Buck
- Piranha (1978) - and also other similar ... 3D etc.
- The Gods Must be Crazy movies
- Phantom of the Paradise 1974
- Apocalypse Now
- Legend of the Lost Tomb (1997)
- Warriors of the Apocalypse
- Firewalker (1986)
- Coronado (2003)
- The Tomb (1986)
- Emmanuelle and the Last Cannibals
- Mountain of the Cannibal God
- Cannibal Holocaust (1980) - (I think the full serial)
- Cannibal Ferox (1981)
- Treasure of the Amazon (1985)

Comment: Since you've been [looking elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/kbt9gn/tomtmovietrying_to_find_movie_for_soon_be_a_year/) you might want to mention other movie suggestions you've already discarded, like *Piranha (1978)*

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095189/?

Comment: Weirdly enough, it's easier to find the whole movie than a trailer... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxotXmoh0Lg

Comment: Cant find any scene i remember in this movie you mentioned.   Specially that masked villain who play pipe organ in a cave.  There is a one thing i cant understand about The Further Adventures Of Tennessee Buck.  Why is it called ''the further'' ?   Are there suppose to be more movies about/with Tennessee Buck ?   I cant find it.

Comment: Nope. It's the one and only film about that character. I think the title is meant to evoke the idea that there's more history to the character. :)

Comment: Guessing this is also you at https://www.movieforums.com/community/showthread.php?anchor=1&p=2148190#post2148190

Comment: Affirmative. Its me 

Comment: I asked the man who make that mask i linked, does he know anything possible about this movie.  Does he maybe know the movie, or a mask/character from that movie. He say that it doesn't sound anything familiar to him.

Comment: I just want to compliment you on how much you've followed-up on this question despite us not having an answer yet.

Comment: How much i search for this, before few nights i think that i dreamed something of this movie - or my mind made up something 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is [The Secret of the Incas' Empire](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093937/)

> Hidden somewhere deep inside a volcano in the mysterious South
> American mountains lies the legendary lost kingdom of the Incas. And
> buried in this kingdom is a fabulous treasure of inestimable value....

Jeep chase:

Meat vs piranha:

Rescue scene:

Organ scene:

Comment: Nice! How did you find it?

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I start to think that i will never watch this again.   How you fond it ?

Comment: I was searching movie for my question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240371/searching-adventure-movie-similar-to-indiana-jones-alan-quatermain-romancin and tried "inca treasure film road", searched for images and opened all that matched (particularly "Secret of the Incas (1954)") and there it was, among other suggestions )

Comment: Again big THANKS !

Comment: You're welcome =)