# Searching adventure movie, similar to Indiana Jones / Alan Quatermain / Romancing The Stone

Tags: story-identification, movie

Saw that movie sometime in 199x (it could be 200x, but don't think so): people searching for the treasure (of ancient inka?).
The only scene I remember is a final one:

- main character gets into some dark place (lower ground or some cave)
- he lifts the hidden cover
- under the cover we see lots of bright shining diamonds (presumably the whole space below is overfilled with the diamonds)
- at the same time a powerful tremor begins, everything starts to fall apart
- "good guys" manage to escape
- it occurs that a new highway is being constructed and big machines are clearing the place out of jungles, so now the whole place is covered by a soil

Adventure is happening in our time.
Movie itself seems to be quite popular at that time.
Searched in google, no luck for now...

Comment: Is there anything sci-fi or fantasy about this movie?  From the description so far it seems like a normal adventure movie...

Comment: @Alith fantasy is about ancient treasure and barriers on the way

Comment: @yaroslav you don't need fantasy to have ancient treasure. When we talk about fantasy we mean Dragons and Magic etc.

Comment: Is it one of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Treasure_hunt_films

Comment: Could be, will check the list

Comment: Whether this is closed or not please don’t edit the answer into the question. If this isn’t on topic but you want to leave the answer for others to find later on it would be best to add the answer as a comment here.

Comment: Finally found the answer: it is "That man from Rio" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Man_from_Rio